# How should I store consecutive f64 values in Wasm memory?

Tags: webassembly

I am writing a [tiny compiler](https://github.com/captbaritone/eel-wasm) that outputs Wasm directly. In my source language all values are `f64`s and they can be written into (and read out of) a fixed size buffer by index.

I am attempting to use a (the?) Wasm memory to store that buffer.

**When storing consecutive `f64` values in memory, should I be deriving the address at runtime by multiplying the index by the byte size of an `f64`, or can I somehow achieve this using `align`/`offset`?**

In my initial approach (which is stupid in retrospect) assumed I could just use consecutive indices and somehow the fact that I was using `f64.store` and `f64.load` it would "just work".

It looked something like this `.wat` file:

```
(module
      (memory 1)
      (func (result f64)
          ;; Write 0 to index 99
          i32.const 99
          f64.const 0
          f64.store

          ;; Write 1 to index 100
          i32.const 100
          f64.const 1
          f64.store

          ;; Read from 99
          i32.const 99
          f64.load
      )
      (export "run" (func 0))
  )
```

I expected this to output `0` but it output `-3.105036184601418e+231` which I assume is because some of the bytes I'm reading when I start reading at index 99 were just written when I wrote to index 100.

**What would a "correct" version of the above `.wat` file -- one that that stores two consecutive `f64` values into memory and then reads one -- look like?**

The official `f64.load`/`f64.store` spec can be found [here](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/instructions.html#memory-instructions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When storing consecutive f64 values in memory, should I be deriving the address at runtime by multiplying the index by the byte size of an f64, or can I somehow achieve this using align/offset?

No, you can't obtain this with align/offset.

You have to multiply all indexes by 8 (since f64 is 64 bit / 8 bit = 8).

You can do that directly in every memory access or another way would be to define two utility functions:

- (result f64) myload(index i32) and
- () mystore(i32 index, f64 value)

These function will then do the load/store at index*8.